# Why netlogo alway shows runtime error when I use behaviorspace?

Tags: runtime-error, netlogo, behaviorspace

I am a beginner of netlogo. I developed a model which runs well by clicking SETUP and GO buttons. But it went wrong when I tried to repeat by BehaviorSpace. I only put one value for each variable.

It shows **"runtime error: requested 8 random agents from a set of only 0 agents group"**. Is there anyone know the reason?

For more details, I loaded a map from a csv file before running BehaviroSpact, and then in turtles were created by `sprout` instead of `crt`. And the setup procedure begins with `clear-turtles` instead of `ca`. I'm not sure if this is the reason.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: From the error it seems clear that at some point, you don't have turtles where you would expect to have them. 
Only using clear-turtles could work if your code is well adapted to it.
Not much more I can say without seeing the code.

Comment: Seconded that we'd need to see the code involved to know what's going wrong. From the error message, it seems like you're doing `n-of 8 ...` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think I got the error: I didn't put load-map procedure in the setup. It could run without behaviorspace because I loaded the map first and then setup and run. But, the setup and run parallelly run other 7, which have no map and cannot sprout turtles based on the patches variables.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your comments. I think it is because I didn't put load-map procedure in the setup. It could run without behaviorspace because I loaded the map first and then set up and ran. But the setup and run parallelly run other 7, which have no map and cannot sprout turtles based on the patches variables.